# Java specific characters in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have written a code to reverse the order of vowels in a given string, but I also need to maintain the original positioning of the vowel capitalization in the string. For example, input : `Java Is Fun` output: `Juvi As Fan` rather than, `JuvI as Fan`.

Here is my Code so far which currently outputs `JuvI as Fan`:

```
static boolean isVowel(char c)
  {
      return (c == 'a' || c == 'A' || c == 'e'
                || c == 'E' || c == 'i' || c == 'I'
                || c == 'o' || c == 'O' || c == 'u'
                || c == 'U');
public static String reverseVowels(String text)
  {
      int index = 0;
      char[] str = text.toCharArray();
      String vowel = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
      {
          if (isVowel(str[i]))
          {
              index++;
              vowel += str[i];
          }
      } 
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
      {
          if (isVowel(str[i]))
          {
              str[i] = vowel.charAt(--index);
          }
      }
      return String.valueOf(str);
```

Comment: Hello, you want to capitalize one vocal only if it is the first letter of a word?

Comment: Then you would need to keep track of which syllable was capitalized or not

Comment: no, it needs the maintain the capitalization of any vowel, so if it were inputted with "JAva Is Fun" the output would be JUvi As FAn"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would record all capital letters (or lowercase if theres more capitals than lowercase in the string) eg.

```java
List<Integer> capitalLetters = new ArrayList<>(); // Positions of capital letters.

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i))) {
         capitalLetters.add(i);
    }
}
text = text.toLowerCase();

int index = 0;
char[] str = text.toCharArray();
String vowel = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (isVowel(str[i])) {
        index++;
        vowel += str[i];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (isVowel(str[i])) {
        str[i] = vowel.charAt(--index);
    }
}

// Recapitalise.
for (int pos : capitalLetters) {
    str[pos] = Character.toUpperCase(str[pos]);
}
return str;
```

I would also change your vowel checking function to:

```java
c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
```

To avoid checking for uppercase letters

Comment: there's no return statement. I've added return str, but it cannot convert char[] to java.lang.String

Comment: `static boolean isVowel(char c)
  {
      return (c == 'a' || c == 'A' || c == 'e'
                || c == 'E' || c == 'i' || c == 'I'
                || c == 'o' || c == 'O' || c == 'u'
                || c == 'U');` the last part of my answer was for replacing the body of this function, not necessary, just cleaner.

Comment: yeah, i'm referring to the first body of code. there's no return statement.

Comment: I've edited, this code should go in main, it calls reversevowels and then sorts out the capitalisation @BeanieLeung

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, it needs to return within the body of code, not through the main

Comment: Should be correctly working for putting in the reverseVowels() function now @BeanieLeung

Comment: i'm still getting the conversion error. cannot convert chat[] to java.lang.String

Comment: oh I changed the return statement to my previous return statement and it worked, thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would search the `String` from left and right, looking for the next vowel character, then swap the two, while preserving the original case. It's a bit verbose but I like to build solutions, that are more generic, to be reusable for different scenarios.

Maybe it's of some value to you.

```java
public class ReverseVowels {

    private static final char[] VOWELS = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String input = "Java Is Fun";
        final String expected = "Juvi As Fan";
        final String actual = reverseVowels(input);
        if (actual.equals(expected)) {
            System.out.println("Awesome! It worked!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the vowels within the given string. Keeps the original character's case.
     *
     * @param s the string to reverse the vowels in
     * @return the manipulated string
     */
    private static String reverseVowels(String s) {
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        int l = -1;
        int r = chars.length;
        do {
            l = indexOfAny(s, VOWELS, l + 1);
            r = lastIndexOfAny(s, VOWELS, r - 1);

            if (l <= r && l > -1) {
                char charLeft = chars[l];
                char charRight = chars[r];
                chars[l] = Character.isUpperCase(charLeft) ? Character.toUpperCase(charRight) : Character.toLowerCase(charRight);
                chars[r] = Character.isUpperCase(charRight) ? Character.toUpperCase(charLeft) : Character.toLowerCase(charLeft);
            }

        } while (l > -1 && r > -1 && r > l);

        return new String(chars);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the next position of any given char in the string, starting at the given position.
     *
     * @param s the string to search
     * @param chars the chars to find
     * @param startPos the start position
     * @return the index of the next char or -1 if char could not be found
     */
    public static int indexOfAny(String s, char[] chars, int startPos) {
        startPos = Math.max(0, startPos);
        for (int i = startPos; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (containsChar(chars, c)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the next position of any given char in the string, looking backwards, starting at the given position.
     *
     * @param s the string to search
     * @param chars the chars to find
     * @param startPos the start position
     * @return the index of the next char or -1 if char could not be found
     */
    public static int lastIndexOfAny(String s, char[] chars, int startPos) {
        startPos = Math.min(s.length() - 1, startPos);
        for (int i = startPos; i >= 0; i--) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (containsChar(chars, c)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true, if the char array chars contains the given char c.
     *
     * @param chars the char array to search in
     * @param c the char to search for
     * @return true if found, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean containsChar(char[] chars, char c) {
        for (char c2 : chars) {
            if (c == c2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```